# Given an array A of N integers between(-100 and 100) Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm practicing Java and my prof has given me this problem:

You're given an array A of N integers (between -100 and 100), calculate the multiplied value of all elements inside the array and return (-1, 0, 1) based on the output.

For instance:

```
A[1,2,3] will return 1 because the output is (6), 
A[-1,2,3] will return -1 because the output is (-6), 
A[1,2,0] will return 0 because the output is (0)
```

Method Definition:

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
}
```

My approach: I was thinking this would be a recursive process because I will multiple have inputs.

**Process one block A[1,2,3], store the value (1) into a newArr[], process another block A[-1,2,3], store the value (-1) into newArr[] and so on... at the end return newArr[] with the proper values in it.**

**What I have so far, now I am kind of stuck..**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int arr[] = {6,-7,8,9};
         int arr1[] = {-6,-7,8,9};
         int arr2[] = {0,-7,8,9};
         System.out.println("[ " + solution(arr) + " ]  => Needs to be -1" );
         System.out.println("[ " + solution(arr1) + " ] => Needs to be  1");
         System.out.println("[ " + solution(arr2) + " ] => Needs to be 0");
         System.out.println("Final return should be (-1, 1, 0)");
    }
    
    public static int solution(int[] A) {
        int temp = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            temp *= A[i];
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

I don't know if this is the right way to proceed, any ideas as to how I should go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First up, in the description of your question you've said "You're given AN array ...", and to calculate the multiple values of all elements inside, then return a value based on the result of the multiplication.  Then in your suggested approach you're talking about processing multiple arrays and returning an array of the results.  Are you actually expected to process multiple arrays and return multiple results - or just process a single array and return a single result?

Comment: We're processing a single array with multiple values passed into it and returning a single array.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're making this more complicated than it has to be.  For each array, just start an accumulator with a value of 1, and then iterate over the array and multiply the accumulator by each value in the array.

Comment: Processing a single array and returning a single array doesn't make sense in terms of how you've described the question.  Your suggested "solution()" method, however, does appear to be the correct approach - accept an array of integers and return a single integer (which will be either -1, 0 or 1).  The logic inside your "solution()" method is obviously what will determine the -1, 0 or 1 return value

Comment: What you've got above seems ok to me.  You have to deal with only returning -1, 0 or 1, but other than that, it seems good.  Here's a hint...`x/Math.abs(x)` will give you `-1` or `1` based on `x` being positive or negative.  It will blow up on `x = 0` though, so you need to handle that as a separate case.  That can be a single line of code that replaces your `return` statement.

Comment: OK, so you've updated the question details now.  Correct me if I'm wrong - but are you now aiming for something where you pass in all 3 of those arrays in one go, and then you get back an array that contains -1, 1, 0?

Comment: @Craig yes that is exactly correct.

Comment: @CryptoFool I will give that a try.

Comment: Hi @Peter.  That makes more sense then.  The approach from Cyrendex will get you there, or alternatively you'd write a wrapper method (that accepts int[][] - an array of integer arrays - as a parameter, and returns int[] - your array of integer results).  However, as Cyrendex points out, it's unclear to us exactly what the final output is that you expect.  Or is it just the fact that your professor will look at the code and determine whether you've approach the task in an appropriate fashion?

Comment: Just see if there is a ´0` in the array, then return `0`. Otherwise count the negative elements - if there is an odd number of negative elements, return `-1`, otherwise `1`.

Comment: This was one of the responses below. @JohannesKuhn

Comment: Yeah, saw that answer after writing my comment.

Answer (score 5):

No need to do any multiplication.

- if any number is `0` return `0` immediately since the product will be zero.
- if the count of negative numbers is even, return 1 since the product of an even number of negatives is a positive.
- else return -1

```
public static int solution(int[] ints) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i : ints) {
        if (i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (i < 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: Nice! You just bypassed the entire numeric overflow issue.

Comment: You could actually replace `int count` with `boolean negative` and do `if (i < 0) { negative = ! negative; }` (or `negative ^= true`)

Comment: Yep.  Didn't even think of that.

Comment: This is the answer that is neatest - but the OP might fail their assignment for not doing the multiplication !!

Comment: @MrR you may be right.  I guess it depends on how the assignment was worded.  It might have been *return -1, 0, or 1 if the product of the numbers is negative, zero, or positive.*  Or the lesson could have been for them to figure out `Math.abs(prod)/prod` for `prod != 0`.  Who knows!?

Comment: Need to check based on the multiplication :/

Comment: If that's the case, what's the object of the lesson?

Comment: Multiply just `Math.signum(e)` for every element.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn That would work.  But then that also is not *calculating the multiplied value of all elements* as stated in the question.  It is only multiplying the signs.  My guess is that this is how the prof stated the problem so as not give away a more optimum solution.  Especially since simple multiplication isn't reliable due to overflow.

Comment: Just use a BigInteger then.

Comment: Now you're really stretching the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Array multiplication left to OP.

Look at [`Integer.signum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#signum(int)) - which will convert the result to 1, 0, -1 for >0, 0, <0.

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know about that function.  But this isn't an answer.  This should b e a comment.

Comment: @CryptoFool Since the assignment (see paragraph 2 in the question) is to take *one* array and return *one* value, and since the only part missing in the question is to do the <0,=0,>0 check, this is exactly the answer to the question. --- The fact that OP is running multiple test cases in the `main` method is immaterial to the assignment.

Comment: I'm wondering whether we should be tagging "student-assignment" for all these assignments .. has "school" just started back ...

Comment: This is a very helpful method in this scenario @MrR

Answer (score 1):

Implementing with a wrapper, along with @Mr R's suggestion

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int arr[] = {6,-7,8,9};
         int arr1[] = {-6,-7,8,9};
         int arr2[] = {0,-7,8,9};

         int[][] array_of_arrays = {arr, arr1, arr2};
         int[] results_array;
         results_array = solution_wrapper(array_of_arrays); 
         
         // then do what you neeed to do with the results_array
         
         System.out.println(results_array[0]);
         System.out.println(results_array[1]);
         System.out.println(results_array[2]);
         System.out.println("[ " + solution(arr) + " ]  => Needs to be -1" );
         System.out.println("[ " + solution(arr1) + " ] => Needs to be  1");
         System.out.println("[ " + solution(arr2) + " ] => Needs to be 0");
         System.out.println("Final return should be (-1, 1, 0)");
    }
    
    public static int solution(int[] A) {
        int temp = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            temp *= A[i];
        }
        return Integer.signum(temp);
    }

    public static int[] solution_wrapper(int[][] allA) {
        int[] rv = new int[allA.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < allA.length; j++) {
            rv[j] = solution(allA[j]);
        }
        return rv;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andreas - yes, previous answer was a sloppy, off-hand attempt that should not have been posted as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare and initialize a final array by using the method you created:

```
int[] finalArr = {solution(arr), solution(arr1), solution(arr2)};
```

However, I'm not sure where you want to return the final array from. You have your main method which doesn't have a return type and your solution method. Are you certain that you're supposed to *return* the final array, or is simply having one enough?